# Show all frames (child and parent) after they lost focus

Tags: java, modal-dialog, lost-focus

I have jFrame from which I creating new jDialog frame with DEFAULT_MODALITY_TYPE. Then I maximizing some other app (like browser or something) so my app is not seen. When I want to show my app and clicking on icon from taskbar, it shows only child frame. What can I do to show all frames without disabling modality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's inappropriate to answer your own question but it may help somebody in future. After some coding I decided to solve this little problem (finally) so I tried many things to do. One that worked for me (maybe it's bad idea to make it like this) is to call mainFrame.setVisible(true) (or mainFrame.toFront(), dunno what is worse to use in this case) from formWindowGainedFocus(WindowEvent evt) event that childFrame is calling.
Once again, tiny code to get rid of this problem:

```
 public class NewFileFrame extends javax.swing.JDialog {
    ...
     private void formWindowGainedFocus(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
         Main.mainFrame.setVisible(true);
         //Main.mainFrame.toFront();
        }
    ...
    }
```